# updating resource cause server (tomcat) to restart (org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I'm making a dynamic  JAVA web project in eclipse Neon .3 using JSP & Servlets with tomcat 7.0 as application server. In my application, after a query, I need to delete a resource (a .png file) and & replace it with a new one (another .png file). The problem arises that once my application is deployed onto the server and then I try to update the resource in my application, following prints on the console:

> **Sep 25, 2018 11:16:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
>
> INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>
> Sep 25, 2018 11:16:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
>
> INFO: Reloading Context with name [/LegalDocSearchEngine] is completed**

After that my objects in the application are set to null and a NullPointerexception occurs. I've tried tomcat 8.0 and 8.5 as well but all in vain. I don't really want my server to reload (whatever the things it reloads).